# Ordenação da mat-angular-table está priorizando letras maiúsculas

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

Estou utilizando o mat sort para ordenar uma mat-table no angular, o problema é que quando ordeno de forma ascendente o algoritmo está levando em conta letras maiúsculas como prioridade, logo, se eu tiver uma tabela com os seguintes nomes:

"Marcos" 
"antonio"

Marcos aparece primeiro na ordenação.

Esse é o algoritmo que usa pra ordenar:

```
sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.descricoesProdutos.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'nome': return this.compare(a.nome, b.nome, isAsc);
        case 'descricao': return this.compare(a.descricao, b.descricao, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }


  compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
  }
```

Meu html:

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver capitalizando antes de comparar:

```
 return this.compare(a.nome.toUpperCase(), b.nome.toUpperCase(), isAsc);
```